# How do i traine the Word2Vec model on domain specific

Tags: python

I have collected some domain-specific data and now want to extract vocabulary from the pre-trained models that are trained in large data using word2ve.

currently, I have not written any code.

How to write the python code to extract vocabulary from the pre-trained model like word2vec Google news

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.